# In Weblogic Server console, how to set the number of rows per page beforehand in domain scripts

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c

On our project, we generate a Weblogic Domain with template files. After we start a fresh generated domain, we see in de WebConsole all lists ( like deployments, queues, ...) default to 10 rows displayed per page.
This is annoying, because we want to see all rows, end we must continually change the number manually.
Is there a way to set the 'Number of rows displayed per page' somehow beforehand, for instance with a script, or in our template files?

Answer (score 1):

I found out myself.
Weblogic console stores this kind of user changes in a server file, named [domain_dir]/servers/[admin_server_name]/data/console/ConsolePreferences.xml.
I manually changed the number of rows to 5000 in all the console-lists we frequently view, stopped the server, and added the forementioned file to our domain template files. 
This is the contents of the ConsolePreferences.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<portlet-preferences>
  <portlet-preference definitionLabel="AppDeploymentsControlPortlet" user="weblogic">
    <preference name="rowsperpage" description="The description" isModifiable="true" isMultivalued="false" value="5000"/>
    <preference name="filterByProperty" description="The description" isModifiable="true" isMultivalued="false" value="false"/>
  </portlet-preference>
  <portlet-preference definitionLabel="WLSMessagingBridgeMonitoringTablePortlet" user="weblogic">
    <preference name="filterByColumn" description="The description" isModifiable="true" isMultivalued="false" value="name"/>
    <preference name="maxrows" description="The description" isModifiable="true" isMultivalued="false" value="All"/>
    <preference name="selectedColumns" description="The description" isModifiable="true" isMultivalued="true">
      <value>name</value>
      <value>serverName</value>
      <value>state</value>
      <value>description</value>
    </preference>
    <preference name="rowsperpage" description="The description" isModifiable="true" isMultivalued="false" value="5000"/>
    <preference name="filterByCriteria" description="The description" isModifiable="true" isMultivalued="false" value=""/>
  </portlet-preference>
  <portlet-preference definitionLabel="WLSMessagingBridgeConfigTablePortlet" user="weblogic">
    <preference name="filterByColumn" description="The description" isModifiable="true" isMultivalued="false" value="name"/>
    <preference name="maxrows" description="The description" isModifiable="true" isMultivalued="false" value="All"/>
    <preference name="selectedColumns" description="The description" isModifiable="true" isMultivalued="true">
      <value>name</value>
      <value>sourceDestinationName</value>
      <value>targetDestinationName</value>
      <value>Scope</value>
      <value>Partitions</value>
    </preference>
    <preference name="rowsperpage" description="The description" isModifiable="true" isMultivalued="false" value="5000"/>
    <preference name="filterByCriteria" description="The description" isModifiable="true" isMultivalued="false" value=""/>
  </portlet-preference>
  <portlet-preference definitionLabel="AppDeploymentsRuntimePortlet" user="weblogic">
    <preference name="filterByColumn" description="The description" isModifiable="true" isMultivalued="false" value="name"/>
    <preference name="maxrows" description="The description" isModifiable="true" isMultivalued="false" value="All"/>
    <preference name="selectedColumns" description="The description" isModifiable="true" isMultivalued="true">
      <value>name</value>
      <value>state</value>
      <value>health</value>
      <value>type</value>
      <value>targets</value>
      <value>scope</value>
      <value>partition</value>
    </preference>
    <preference name="rowsperpage" description="The description" isModifiable="true" isMultivalued="false" value="5000"/>
    <preference name="filterByCriteria" description="The description" isModifiable="true" isMultivalued="false" value=""/>
  </portlet-preference>
  <portlet-preference definitionLabel="JmsBridgedestinationJMSBridgeDestinationTablePortlet" user="weblogic">
    <preference name="filterByColumn" description="The description" isModifiable="true" isMultivalued="false" value="Name"/>
    <preference name="maxrows" description="The description" isModifiable="true" isMultivalued="false" value="All"/>
    <preference name="selectedColumns" description="The description" isModifiable="true" isMultivalued="true">
      <value>Name</value>
      <value>AdapterJndiName</value>
      <value>ScopeName</value>
      <value>Partitions</value>
    </preference>
    <preference name="rowsperpage" description="The description" isModifiable="true" isMultivalued="false" value="5000"/>
    <preference name="filterByCriteria" description="The description" isModifiable="true" isMultivalued="false" value=""/>
  </portlet-preference>
  <portlet-preference definitionLabel="GlobalJDBCDataSourceMonitorTablePortlet" user="weblogic">
    <preference name="filterByColumn" description="The description" isModifiable="true" isMultivalued="false" value="Name"/>
    <preference name="maxrows" description="The description" isModifiable="true" isMultivalued="false" value="All"/>
    <preference name="selectedColumns" description="The description" isModifiable="true" isMultivalued="true">
      <value>Name</value>
      <value>dataSourceType</value>
      <value>Resource</value>
      <value>DataSourceScope</value>
      <value>server</value>
      <value>State</value>
      <value>ActiveConnectionsAverageCount</value>
      <value>ActiveConnectionsCurrentCount</value>
      <value>ActiveConnectionsHighCount</value>
    </preference>
    <preference name="rowsperpage" description="The description" isModifiable="true" isMultivalued="false" value="5000"/>
    <preference name="filterByCriteria" description="The description" isModifiable="true" isMultivalued="false" value=""/>
  </portlet-preference>
  <portlet-preference definitionLabel="JMSSystemModuleConfigGeneralPortlet" user="weblogic">
    <preference name="[moduleresources]filterByCriteria" description="The description" isModifiable="true" isMultivalued="false" value=""/>
    <preference name="[moduleresources]rowsperpage" description="The description" isModifiable="true" isMultivalued="false" value="5000"/>
    <preference name="[moduleresources]maxrows" description="The description" isModifiable="true" isMultivalued="false" value="All"/>
    <preference name="[moduleresources]filterByColumn" description="The description" isModifiable="true" isMultivalued="false" value="Name"/>
    <preference name="[moduleresources]selectedColumns" description="The description" isModifiable="true" isMultivalued="true">
      <value>Name</value>
      <value>Type</value>
      <value>JndiName</value>
      <value>SubDeploymentName</value>
      <value>Targets</value>
    </preference>
  </portlet-preference>
  <portlet-preference definitionLabel="GlobalJDBCDataSourceTablePortlet" user="weblogic">
    <preference name="filterByColumn" description="The description" isModifiable="true" isMultivalued="false" value="Name"/>
    <preference name="maxrows" description="The description" isModifiable="true" isMultivalued="false" value="All"/>
    <preference name="selectedColumns" description="The description" isModifiable="true" isMultivalued="true">
      <value>Name</value>
      <value>DataSourceType</value>
      <value>JndiName</value>
      <value>Targets</value>
      <value>DisplayScopeName</value>
      <value>Partitions</value>
    </preference>
    <preference name="rowsperpage" description="The description" isModifiable="true" isMultivalued="false" value="5000"/>
    <preference name="filterByCriteria" description="The description" isModifiable="true" isMultivalued="false" value=""/>
  </portlet-preference>
</portlet-preferences>
```